# Filter tree hierarchy using HQL in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am facing an issue in Hibernate:

- There is entity A
- An instance of A can be linked to another A through an instance of Entity B
- A has an one-to-many association to B
- B has a many-to-one association to A

So I have a tree like hierarchy looking like this

```
                     A(*)
                     |
    |----------------|--------------|
    B<-A(*)          B<-A(*)        B<-A
       |                               |
       |                               |
   |-------|                           |
   B<-A    B<-A(*)                     B<-A(*)
```

There is a property in A named enabled. I want to write a HQL query that fetches all top-level As and their Bs that have an A with enabled=true (which are marked in the tree with *).

In essence, the tree I would like to get as a result for the example would be this

```
                     A(*)
                     |
    |----------------|
    B<-A(*)          B<-A(*)        
       |                               
       |                              
       ----|                          
           B<-A(*)
```

How can I achieve this?